# How can I see the definition of an alias in lldb on macOS?

Tags: ios, macos, debugging, llvm, lldb

I know how to define my own alias's etc, but I can't figure out how to view the definition of already defined alias's like `image`:

```
  image     -- Commands for accessing information for one or more target modules.
```

The above alias is central to inspecting e.g. symbol information in the target program, and so I'd like to see how it's defined in terms of the main commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better way that produces less noisy output, but `help image` includes this at the end of its output:

```
'image' is an abbreviation for 'target modules'
```

That seems to be the case for aliases in general.

Comment: thanks for your input. I've been looking into aliases. Do you know how `x/...` is implemented? `x` is an alias for `memory read`, but I can't see `x/` specified as an alias. Furthermore, `help memory read` doesn't say anything about `x` taking `/` as a sub-command.

Comment: I don't know how the mapping of `/` is achieved in terms of the alias definition, but it corresponds to the `-G <gdb format>` option of `memory read`.

Comment: how do you see it corresponds to the `-G <gdb format>`? option of memory read?

Comment: I don't know a way to get lldb to show that it corresponds. It's just that I know that it does. That `x/...` syntax is supported for gdb compatibility. See the [GDB to LLDB command map](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html). Search for "4xw". Actually, looking at that, I see that "/..." is supported directly by `memory read`, and so isn't part of the `x` alias.

Comment: `/x` is not handled by the alias mechanism.  At present, it is applied by hand in the command parser to certain commands - ones where supplying a format is a common activity and where you'd have to put in a `--` as well as the format.

Comment: There really should be a more straightforward way to get to the definition of an alias.  I filed: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43258 if anybody wants to follow along (or has some spare time on their hands and would like to give lldb hacking a try...)

Comment: @JimIngham, why do you say "ones where supplying a format is a common activity and where you'd have to put in a -- as well as the format."? Can you give an example?

Comment: Consider the `expr` command.  It is a "raw" command - meaning the command line is mostly unparsed.  That's why you can say `expr printf("hi")` not `expr printf(\"hi\")` But that means if you do want to pass an option you have to tell lldb where the options end, using `--`.  So setting a format for expr means you would have to do: `expr -f x -- <expression>`.  That's getting pretty verbose.  `expr/x <expression>` is much more compact.  Since `p` is an alias for `expr --` you actually can't pass flags to it.  Having the /format work in that case too makes using `p` much more convenient.